# Very simple but still complicated just want to Add parameter to SSRS with Dynamic data

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am creating a SSRs report, I just took 2 parameters one is salary & and other `>`, `<`, or `=` operators, but that is dynamic what user selects in drop down that comparison  option should come.

My code is as follows in SSRs report

```
DECLARE  @PARAM VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @sqlcommand varchar(1000)

-- DECLARE @salary varchar(1000)
-- SET @salary='40000'

SET @PARAM='<'

SET @sqlcommand = 'SELECT A.EmpID, A.FirstName, A.LastName, C.Address, C.City, C.PostalCode, C.Country, C.Region, B.Salary FROM ((Employee A INNER JOIN Salary B ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID) INNER JOIN  Address C ON A.EmpID = C.EmpID) WHERE  B.salary ' + @PARAM + ''+ CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Salary))

PRINT @sqlcommand

EXEC (@sqlcommand)
```

So for me one salary is parameter and other comparison operator when I run I get this error:

> Microsoft Report Builder
>
> An error occurred while executing the query.
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select A.EmpID, A.FirstName, A.LastName, C.Address, C.City, C.PostalCode, C.Country, C.Region, B.Salary FROM ((Employee A INNER JOIN Salary B ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID) INNER JOIN  Address C ON A.EmpID = C.EmpID) where  B.salary <' to data type int.

Can you please help? I know it's simple but I am struggling to concatenate since days and no luck.

Comment: Why do you do this `CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Salary))`? That's what causes the problem by the way, as you are trying to add an `INT` to a `VARCHAR`, so the assumption is made that you want to convert the text to an integer, and it doesn't convert, hence the error message.

Comment: its giving error without converting as well Richard :(, so i thought to convert n try

Comment: Also, what's the `''` for between @PARAM and @Salary? I think this is probably where your problems started? Are you trying to add a single quote or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `CONVERT` your salary to `VARCHAR` not `INT`, give this a go;

```sql
    Use MytestDB

DECLARE  @PARAM VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @sqlcommand varchar(1000)

declare @salary varchar(1000)

set @salary='40000'

SET @PARAM='<'

SET @sqlcommand='Select A.EmpID, A.FirstName, A.LastName, C.Address, C.City, C.PostalCode, C.Country, C.Region, B.Salary FROM ((Employee A INNER JOIN Salary B ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID) INNER JOIN  Address C ON A.EmpID = C.EmpID) WHERE  B.salary ' + @PARAM + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Salary)

SELECT @sqlcommand
```

Comment: yes perfect thanks so where i was wrong in converting to CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Salary)